# Use remove() function to delete elements containg specific substring from list

Tags: python, arrays

I was trying to delete some elements which contain specific substring of a list. For this reason, I tried to use the [remove()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/array.html?highlight=remove#array.array.remove) to solve my problem.

However, remove() did not solve my problem and I even found out that the for-loop didn't loop through. Does any one have any idea? Based on the documentation from Python, I know remove() does only delete the occurrent element.

The following is my example code and its output:

```py
l = ['x-1', 'x-2', 'x-3', 'x-4', 'x-5', 'x-6', 'x-7', 'x-8', 'x-9', 'x-10', 'x-11']
for i in l:
    print(i)
    if 'x-1' in i:
        l.remove(i)
        print('l after removed element: ', l)
print(l)
```

Output

```
x-1
l after removed element:  ['x-2', 'x-3', 'x-4', 'x-5', 'x-6', 'x-7', 'x-8', 'x-9', 'x-10', 'x-11']
x-3
x-4
x-5
x-6
x-7
x-8
x-9
x-10
l after removed element:  ['x-2', 'x-3', 'x-4', 'x-5', 'x-6', 'x-7', 'x-8', 'x-9', 'x-11']
['x-2', 'x-3', 'x-4', 'x-5', 'x-6', 'x-7', 'x-8', 'x-9', 'x-11']
```

Comment: Sometimes a list comprehension is useful in this situation; `l = [i for i in l if 'x-1' not in i]`

Comment: I agrre, this is also a good approach but I just want to figure out how does remove() work. Thank you!

Comment: `remove()` just removes an element. The problem is when doing it while iterating over the list. You remove an item and change the structure of the list. Now the iterator of the list "skips" an element because the elements "moved" unexpectedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're modifying the list while enumerating it. Manage your *for* loop by using a copy of the list as follows:

```
l = ['x-1', 'x-2', 'x-3', 'x-4', 'x-5', 'x-6', 'x-7', 'x-8', 'x-9', 'x-10', 'x-11']
for i in l[:]: # <--- here's the change
    print(i)
    if 'x-1' in i:
        l.remove(i)
        print('l after removed element: ', l)
print(l)
```

Comment: So l[:] is a copy of l, correct? So you use l[:] to loop through the list and so that all elements that contain substring can be removed. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Kai-ChunLin Correct. Try it